# Get TypeError Network Request Failed using react native fetch json url

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I would like to create simple apps that make user can post data to json.

Here is my code.

```
  componentDidMount = () => {

  fetch('https://site.json', 
     {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": 'application/json',  
        },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        value: 'React POST Request Example' 
        })
      }
     ).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))  
  .catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err));
   }
```

But finally,  I get an error  `api Erorr:  [TypeError: Network request failed]`

Is it Cors block my access???

Any idea how to solve it, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the URL. The same code working fine with other urls like.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          value: 'React POST Request Example',
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log('api Erorr: ', err));
    }}
```